# Could you explain what is wrong with my code about class and form?

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I defined class which name is typeImage.
Then I made new form then load class.

there is the code

```
   namespace CardScan
    {
      public partial class ResultForm : Form
      {
         string titleName;
         TypeImage means;

         public ResultForm(TypeImage _means, int i, string _titleName)
         {
           means=_means;
           means.labeling(i);
           means.saveLabeled();

           titleName = _titleName;
           InitializeComponent();
           viewResult();
         }
```

This is the code in my Main form

```
        ResultForm child = new ResultForm(means[i], i, titleName);
        child.ShowDialog();
```

Error message is Error  1 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'CardScan.TypeImage' is less accessible than method 'CardScan.ResultForm.ResultForm(CardScan.TypeImage, int, string)

I can't understand what is wrong with.

Please help me. thank you.

I add class typeImage code

```
class TypeImage
{
    public Bitmap sourceImage;
    public Bitmap resultImage;
    public Bitmap labeledImage;
    public int[] sumArray;
    public byte[] sourceArray;
    public byte[] resultArray;
    public byte[] labeledArray;
    public int[] arrLabel;
    public int nArr;
    public int height;
    public int width;
    public int imageCount = 0;
    public bool isSet = false;

    public void Set(int h, int w)
    {
        this.height = h;
        this.width = w;
        sumArray = new int[height * width * 3];
        sourceArray = new byte[height * width * 3];
        resultArray = new byte[height * width * 3];
        arrLabel = new int[100];
        sumArray.Initialize();
        nArr = 0;
        isSet = true;
    }

    public void getSource(int index, string path)
    {
        using (Bitmap img = new Bitmap(path + "\\" + CardTypeConverter.getFileName(index) + ".bmp"))
        {              
            ImageTypeConverter.ImageToArray(img, img.Height, img.Width, sourceArray);
        }
    }

    public void getMeanImage()
    {
        if (this.imageCount > 0)
        {             
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    sourceArray[y * width * 3 + x * 3 + 2] = (byte)((double)sumArray[y * width * 3 + x * 3 + 2] / imageCount);
                    sourceArray[y * width * 3 + x * 3 + 1] = (byte)((double)sumArray[y * width * 3 + x * 3 + 1] / imageCount);
                    sourceArray[y * width * 3 + x * 3 + 0] = (byte)((double)sumArray[y * width * 3 + x * 3 + 0] / imageCount);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void saveSource()
    {
        sourceImage = ImageTypeConverter.ArrayToImage(this.sourceArray, this.height, this.width);

    }

    public void saveResult()
    {
        resultImage = ImageTypeConverter.ArrayToImage(this.resultArray, this.height, this.width);
        labeledArray = new byte[this.resultArray.Length];
        Array.Copy(this.resultArray, labeledArray, this.resultArray.Length);

    }

    public void saveLabeled()
    {
        labeledImage = ImageTypeConverter.ArrayToImage(this.labeledArray, this.height, this.width);

    }

    public void labeling(int i)
    {
        DLLImport.Labeling(labeledArray, this.height, this.width, this.arrLabel, ref this.nArr);
        string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "5.Labeling");      //Image 폴더 생성
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
        ImageTypeConverter.ArrayToImage(labeledArray, this.height, this.width).Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\5.Labeling\\image" + (i+1) + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    }

    public void Free()
    {
        this.sourceArray = null;
        this.resultArray = null;
        this.sumArray = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the Class TypeImage?

Comment: Your TypeImage class access modifier should be public as you are using it from outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the accessibility modifier of your `TypeImage` class to `public`. This is because your `ResultForm` is `public` and accessible to the external world, but if anyone tries to construct an object of `ResultForm`, they'll not be able to do so because one of the parameters required by the `ResultForm`'s constructor is invisible to them. Therefore the compiler doesn't allow this.